# How to extract data from object(Zend_Db_Table_Rowset)

Tags: php, zend-framework, rowset

I have that object(Zend_Db_Table_Rowset)

```
object(Zend_Db_Table_Rowset)#183 (10) { ["_data":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(18) { 
["panel_id"]=> string(2) "37" ["group_id"]=> string(2) "19" ["panel_language"]=> string(2) "en" 
["panel_name"]=> string(24) "IRAQI NATIONAL COMPANIES" ["panel_heading"]=> string(24) "IRAQI 
NATIONAL COMPANIES" ["panel_content"]=> string(404) "
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus turpis velit, egestas a venenatis 
at,pharetra at est. Suspendisse sagittis dapibus congue. Maecenas hendrerit, ipsum quis iaculis 
dignissim, leo enim varius diam,
iaculis pretium magna diam non velit. Etiam congue nisl sed quam lobortis ultricies. Vestibulum 
ipsum tellus, fermentum vel
tempor eu, blandit
```

and I want to get **panel_heading**, **panel_content**

I'm trying to do this

```
$panels->panel_heading;
$panels->panel_content;
```

and I get that notice:

```
 Notice: Undefined property: Zend_Db_Table_Rowset::$panel_heading
```

is there an easy way for getting the data out ??

Comment: Could you provide var_dump($panels->toArray()))

Comment: @Dmitry  `array(1) { [0]=> array(18) { ["panel_id"]=> string(2) "37" ["group_id"]=> string(2) "19" ["panel_language"]=> string(2) "en" ["panel_name"]=> string(24) "IRAQI NATIONAL COMPANIES" ["panel_heading"]=> string(24) "IRAQI NATIONAL COMPANIES" ["panel_content"]=> string(404) "
t`

Comment: Try use foreach. For example: foreach($panels as panel) and panel->panel_content.

Comment: @Dmitry I've got `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code below:

`foreach($panels as $panel)`
    `echo $panel->panel_content`